# remove thesis title from the abstract section

Tags: latex, abstract, tex

this xelatex template's abstract section automatically add thesis title at top,
here's the template live demo in overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/jkrpnmrnmqwz

i've looked around for hours and still cannot solve it, it seems it's not a common situation in english template.
the abstract page is not even used, so i guess some other packages include it?
i've also checked the abstract package documentation pdf, no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to try what follows. Go to [your project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/jkrpnmrnmqwz) and select the class file `oucthesis.cls`.

Scroll down to line 252:

[image: screenshot of code]

Now comment line 252 with a `%` character at the beginning of the line:

```latex
%    \fontsize{16\bp@}{26.67\bp@}\sffamily\@title
```

By the way, you can comment all the three lines from 251 to 253.

This should make it, otherwise please comment below my answer!